# Using 6 yes-no questions to find a card in a standard deck

Tags: discrete-mathematics, card-games

The following is the question:

I have chosen a single card from a standard 52-card deck. You may ask any questions whose
answer is “yes” or “no” about the card, even complicated ones like “is your card either a picture
card in clubs or the five of any suit?”.

Give a list of 6 yes-no questions which, when asked, ensures that after those six questions
have been answered, you will know exactly what card I have.

Argue that it is impossible to come up with a list of five yes-no questions which would
always let you know exactly what card I have.

Here is what I have so far:

1.) Is your card red

2.) Is your card a heart or a spade

3.) Is your card less than or equal to 7?

4.) Is your card less than or equal to 4, or a face card?

5.) Is your card in {A,2},{5,6},{8,9},{J,Q}.

6.) Is your card in {A,3},{5,7},{8,10},{J,K}.

EDIT:
Here is the final product after comments

As for the second part of the question, I believe the reason this isn't possible is that each yes or no question needs to eliminate half of the possibilities regardless of the answer. Because of this, with five questions, you will be left with two possibilities every time.

Comment: Maybe you'd find it easier if you imagined the cards were labled $\#1-\#52$.  Note:  I don't understand your reasoning as regards $5$ questions.  How many cards could you identify if you had $5$ questions?

Comment: The first two steps are just binary search where you exclude half the possibilities. Just keep going.

Comment: For the first part: Is your card in the set {A,2,3,4,5,6,7}? Yes. Is your card in the set {A,2,3,4}? No. Is your card in the set {5,6}? Yes. Is your card a 5? No. Then it's a 6.

Comment: Okay, so here is where I am having difficulty. I had thought of is your card in {A,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}. That sufficiently splits the remaining in two. However, the question is your card in set {A,2,3,4} is only useful is the answer to the previous was Yes. If the answer to the previous is no, then {A,1,2,3} does not help.

Comment: @lex320 I think you are forgetting that a deck of cards doesn't have any card numbered 1

Comment: I think I see your objection. Usually when we have a guessing game like this, you can use a strategy where the answer to the previous question tells you which question to ask next. But in your question you are supposed to write just six questions ahead of time. So instead of only asking about half of the remaining possibilities at each step, you must ask a question that divides the remaining possibilities in half no matter what the answer to the previous question was, just like you did with your second question.

Comment: You should be able to adapt the questions to the answers you have already gotten. E.g. First ask "is it red?" Then if you get yes, ask "Is it hearts?" and if you get no ask "Is it clubs?" If you aren't allowed to do this, no matter, you simply combine the two possible questions. The second question then becomes "Is it hearts or clubs?" Same result. You can do the same with the number values on the cards.

Comment: Okay, yes, 1 is not in the deck. And yes, given you could ask yes or no questions in a branching path based on answers, I would know what to ask. Is this the only way to accomplish this, or are there 6 concrete questions that could give you the same results without branching paths.

Comment: Okay, I have added question three based on what you said Arthur, that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of six questions that can identify the card,
where you are only allowed to write six questions total that must be asked
in order no matter what answers you get,
you have already figured out the first two questions.
For the third question, as suggested in comments, you could ask if the rank of the card is in the set $\{A,2,3,4,5,6,7\}.$
This splits the remaining possibilities in half no matter which suit the first two questions revealed.

For the fourth question, you can take all the questions that would have been the fourth in all the branches you would have taken if you were allowed to make up questions depending on the previous answers, and combine them;
that is, if "yes" on the third question means you want to know if the card is an
$x,$ $y,$ or $z$ and "no" means you want to ask if it is a $u,$ $v,$ or $w,$
then ask if it is a $u,$ $v,$ $w,$ $x,$ $y,$ or $z$.
Similarly, for the fifth question ask about all the possible values you could have asked about in the fifth question in any branch, and similarly for the sixth question.

This is essentially the same strategy you took in identifying the suits,
where on the second question you ask if the card is a heart (even if the first answer was "no", implying that it cannot be a heart) or a spade (even if the first answer was "yes", implying that it cannot be a spade).

A way to envision the questions is that you somehow make a map from the cards in a standard deck to the numbers from $0$ to $63$ written in binary.
(Some numbers will not be used, and that's OK.)
Then your first question will be equivalent to whether the first binary bit is $1,$ your second question is whether the second binary bit is one, etc.
The first two questions that you devised correspond to mapping the hearts to the numbers $48$ through $63,$ diamonds to $32$ through $47$,
spades to $16$ through $31$, and clubs to $0$ through $15.$

Note that if your questions are efficient, you may be able to identify the card after just five questions. It is only in some circumstances that you will need to ask six.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense to me. I have updated the question with 6 questions using this, and I believe these 6 are solid.

Comment: Yes, those questions look good to me. I think if you do the mapping to binary numbers I suggested, you will end up listing the ranks of each suit in an unusual order, but that doesn't matter. All that matters is only one card maps to each number.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say a set of $n$ questions sufficiently identifies that each card is unique, hence a combination of $n$ yes and no's can decisively tell you what the card is, The total combination of yes and no's is given by $2^n$, therefore $2^n \ge 52$, and rightly said by you, $5$ doesn't satisfy this